# problemas subiendo documentos en yii2

Tags: php, mvc, yii2

tengo un problema subiendo unos documentos en mi app, me guarda valores en la bdd pero cuando reviso la carpeta donde guardo los archivos está vacía.

Acá les colocaré mi código y el error que me da el navegador.

en mi controlador

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Documento();

        // $id_usiario = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
         //$documento = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('documento');
        
         $this->documento = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('documento');
        //  echo'<pre>';var_dump($documento);
        
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_documento]);
        }

        // echo'<pre>';var_dump(Yii::$app->request->isPost);echo'<pre>';

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

en mi modelo

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $insert = $this->isNewRecord;

         $documento = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('documento');

        foreach ( $documento  as $key => $value) { 
            if($key == "name"){
                // var_dump($value);
                $nombre = $value;
                // var_dump($nombre);
            }
        }
        $data =[];
        $data["name"] = $nombre;
  
        if ($insert) {
            $this->id_documento = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8);
            // var_dump($this->id_documento );
            $this->nombre_documento = $data["name"];
            $this->minuta_documento = '$data["name"]';
            $this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;            
        }
        // return parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);
        $saved = parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);

        if (!$saved) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($insert) {
            $documentoPath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/storage/documento/' . $this->nombre_documento );
            if(!is_dir(dirname($documentoPath))) {
                FileHelper::createDirectory(dirname($documentoPath));
            }
              var_dump($documentoPath);
            $this->saveAs($documentoPath);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Y en mi vista

```
<div class="d-md-flex justify-content-center align-content-center flex-column py-5 text-center">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="upload-icon d-md-flex flex-row align-self-center justify-content-center">
    <i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Arrastra tu documento para poder enviarlo</p>
        <p class="text-muted">Tú documento ser privado hasta le momento en que decidas enviarlo</p>

        <?php ActiveForm::begin(
            [
                'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]
            ]) ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            selecciona tu documento
            <input type="file" name="documento" id="archivoDocumento">
        </button>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

cuando reviso el navegador me arroja este error "Call to a member function saveAs() on null" pero cuando hago var_dump por ejemplo a var_dump($documentoPath); en el modelo me arroja esto , "string(75) "C:\xampp\htdocs\micarpeta/frontend/web/storage/documento/yii-guide-2.0-es.pdf" según si sube el documento, pero al revisar la carpeta no hay nada, de verdad no doy con la solución, gracias a todos de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando subes documentos van al directorio temporal y deben ser movidos a su ubicación definitiva. En $data tienes los valores actuales y debes usarlos para hacer el movimiento usando move() aplicado a $data y usando $documentoPath como destino.

Comment: @quevedo el move lo aplicaría justamente en if del insert? o cuando estoy en este paso del código "$this->saveAs($documentoPath);"?

Comment: Debes aplicarlo en lugar de saveAS() . Para ser exacto. Debes usar el método `move_uploaded_file()` la documentación oficial en español está en [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file)

Comment: El resultado es el mismo "Call to a member function saveAs() on null" y guarda datos en la bdd, mas no el archivo en la carpeta que estoy creando.

Comment: Revisaste estar usando los datos del archivo subido al directorio tmp?

Comment: @quevedo creo que no he revisado esa parte, pensaba que guardaba directamente en la carpeta que le había asignado (soy nuevo usando yii2 , disculpa si redundo tanto :s)

Comment: @quevedo cuando le hago un var_dump a $documento me trae esto 

`object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#124 (6) {

  ["name"]=>
  string(121) "Alexander Makarov, _ Bogdanov, Andrew_ Dmitry Eliseev - Yii2 Application Development Cookbook-Packt Publishing (2016).pdf"

  ["tempName"]=>
  string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php23C5.tmp"

  ["type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"

  ["size"]=>
  int(5503480)

  ["error"]=>
  int(0)

  ["_tempResource":"yii\web\UploadedFile":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`

Comment: @quevedo el archivo aparece, pero se va de la carpeta tmp de xammp.

Comment: Si. El archivo está en tmp hasta que es movido o hasta que php sirve la respuesta. Una vez cumplidas esas condiciones es borrado por el colector de basura. **Por eso debes moverlo**

Comment: @quevedo disculpa, podrías darme un ejemplo? , yo reviso la carpeta de temporales y el archivo se genera, pero cuando le pongo mi path, no se guarda nada , pero pregunto,  al usar  "move_uploaded_file($documento, $documentoPath);" $documentoPath, tendría que ser SOLO la dirección de la carpeta?

Comment: Los archivos son subidos en la superglobal $_FILES si no los coge el controlador puedes tomarlos de allí.  Tienes que tomar la dirección `"C:\xampp\tmp\php23C5.tmp"` y usarla como origen para el método que te indiqué: move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )

Comment: C:\xampp\tmp\php23C5.tmp corresponde a $filename y tu path de destino a $destination. El dump te muestra que debes usar la clave "tempName" para recoger el valor

Answer (score 0):

En tu modelo, luego de

```
$documento = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('documento');
```

Agrega

```
$this->documento->saveAs('tu/carpeta/de/archivos/' . $this->documento->baseName . '.' . $this->documento->extension);
```

Esa línea guarda el archivo. Luego haces las operaciones para guardar el registro en la base de datos.

Luego de resolver eso, te recomiendo usar el método `beforeSave()` y `afterSave()` para operaciones en el modelo. No es recomendable sobrescribir el método `save()`.

Es mejor usar `beforeSave()` para establecer los datos del modelo en la base de datos y `afterSave()` guardar el archivo.